# Create Alerts via Script for Azure Stream Analytics Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-stream-analytics

Appears there is a gap in the Powershell Cmdlet coverage for scripted Azure Stream Analytics Job create / modification.

I am searching, but have not found, for a cmdlet or other mechanism that can turn Stream Analytics Job Diagnostics ON and create Alerts based on metrics.  We can certainly use the Azure Portal to do so but need a way to script it.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic and metric alerts are not specific to Stream Analytics, and can be configured programmatically using Azure Monitor for Azure services.
Here's the [link to their PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-alerts-powershell).

Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks

JS